# TypeScript import statements converted from JavaScript

Tags: typescript, webpack

I moved some working JavaScript code into a TypeScript npm module for reuse I had issues. I made the following changes to imports statements to get the code working again:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
```

became (has React TypeScript types installed):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
```

Helmet had TypeScript types, but had an issue, so I use this format for libraries with no types:

```
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
```

became:

```
const Helmet = require('react-helmet');
```

and then sometimes I need to call default:

```
import TopBarProgressIndicator from "react-topbar-progress-indicator"
```

becomes:

```
const TopBarProgressIndicator = require('react-topbar-progress-indicator').default;
```

Are there any TypeScript config changes (current or planned) I could make so this is unnecessary, or a better way to do this as it is time consuming and error prone? I am aware of allowJs flag for tsconfig, that seems to process `.js` files, but I would like it to be a `.ts` file. I am currently using TypeScript 1.8.10 and webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a file in my project for ambient declarations (I call it `declarations.d.ts`) - if I'm using a library that doesn't have types defined, I just add a stub definition in that file that exports an `any` value.

```
declare module "react-helmet" {
    var _temp: any;
    export = _temp;
}
```

This will allow you to import the module using `import * as Helmet from "react-helmet"`, as you are doing with React already.

There's a [planned update to TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615) that will allow you to do this with a much smaller syntax. It'll look something like this:

```
declare module "react-helmet";
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that before, but I think that is even more work and still can require changes to the import statement.